# Creation of courses in bulk using API

Tags: google-classroom

Using classroom API (`courses.create()` method) we are able to create one course, but I want to create courses in bulk using API.

Is there any method in API to do so? if so what is the method that I should use?

Similarly how to add teachers or students to a course in bulk?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can [batch](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/batch) the requests together. Be aware of [API usage limits](https://developers.google.com/classroom/limits) though.

Comment: Batch requests would help me out I hope so thanks for that, but I want to know one more thing that is : can I create google apps for education accounts using API so that I add them to courses as you said?

Comment: Lets assume I have already created my users on our web application and they have unique Id's, parameters like name etc..

Comment: To create users see: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users

Comment: My question is that we can create users manually one by one or in bulk by uploading CSV through admin console, like way can I create users by calling API in our web application with configured patterns? I should not use any manual work. Thanks in advance...

Comment: we're getting pretty far off topic from your original question which was about Classroom. If further discussion is necessary start a new question but the users create API call can use the same batch methods as the classroom create does.